# How do I update assets folder only without updating a whole app?

Tags: android, auto-update

I am currently developing an application for my Class Routine and it changes periodically in a 3-4 weeks.I have an application with local index files inside assets folder of an application. So I am looking for any suggestion to update only  assets folder such that if Routine changes user can easily update the new Routine ( i.e content of assets folder only ) without the need to update the whole application. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> So I am looking for any suggestion

You need to make update-able stuff external and downloadable, so your app can fetch new version when needed.

Comment: and How can I do that...I can put the new changed html files to webserver or to my Dropbox, but what will be the code to achieve such functionality. Does application will itself check the updates or can I put some button in there such that user can manually check if new Routine is available  or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, assets and application resources are read only and cannot be changed at run-time. You can only change be updating the application.

You have one of two ways

- Update the entire application, and the user has to actually update the app, and they can opt out of doing that.
- Depend on downloading your data from a remote server, and periodically, or with each app launch you can check for updates on your existing content.